# How do I sync Outlook 2011 and Google Calendar?

Tags: data-synchronization, google-calendar, ms-office

I am using Outlook 2011 for Mac (the office uses Exchange) and have some Google Calendars I am using for home. How do I get 2-way sync working between Outlook and Google? I could do this with iCal but its Exchange support is sorely lacking and therefore not an option.

Comment: I have spent hours looking for ways to effectively sync Windows 2011 Outlook calendar with gmail calendar and am not prepared to spend all this time on what should be an easy feature.
I have gone away from Nokia and Windows as I am feed up with this never ending syc problem between Outlook and gmail. Android is much better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this feature is available yet (ever?).  You may be able to get this going by having Outlook sync with your iCal, and have iCal sync with your Google cal.  Even that though, (Outlook sync with iCal) isn't available yet, and probably the biggest gripe Mac users have with Outlook ATM.  I wouldn't be too surprised if there's a 3rd party plugin or piece of software that will do that for you by now.  Honestly though, I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a work around to synchronize Outlook 2011 with Google Calendar!

First I set up Sync Services to sync my Outlook 2011 calendar to iCal calendar. I make sure that I have all the categories that I want to have in my Outlook and create some event for each category so that it gets created in the iCal calendar as well.

Then I downloaded this software called "[Spanning Sync 3](http://spanningsync.com/?r=6XV3DY)", installed it and set it up with my Google account (Spanning Sync is a paid software with a 15 day trial if you want to try it first). After that, I can do the setup for syncing the iCal with the Google Calendar by mapping the categories in iCal to the categories in the Google account.

What happens is that when you create, modify or delete an event in Outlook, this event gets synced to iCal which in turn gets picked up by Spanning Sync and syncs to Google Calendar. Similarly, any changes in Google Calendar gets synced to iCal via Spanning Sync which in turn gets synced back to Outlook. This solution does not involve CalDAV to sync to Google Calendar.

Hope this will help someone else out there :)

Comment: SpanningSync is no longer supported (July 2012)

Answer (score -2):

one way sync is possible, but I didn’t hear for 2 way sync between Outlook 2011 & Google Calendars. Recently I had posted a blog for synchronization of Mac Outlook calendars to Google calendar, you can try this method once. And as I am hoping somehow it will assist you.

Source Blog Link: http://mailtroubleshooter.tumblr.com/post/109556653818/how-to-sync-mac-outlook-calendar-with-google

Comment: Please give the information here. Answers should be stand alone and not rely on outside resources. Thos resources can be used to give more details

Comment: Also, the link no longer works.